# how to check if value (int) exists in Enum generic java android

Tags: java, android, generics, enums

check if integer value exist in Enum constant Java
Example

```
enum Days{
SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY;
}

checkFunction(Days, 5) // true
checkFunction(Days, -1) // false
checkFunction(Days, 10) // false
```

Comment: What is the context of 5, -1, 10?  Ordinal value?  Day of the week?

Comment: There is already such an enum you could use out of the box: [`DayOfWeek`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#of(int)) To check if an `int` represents a `DayOfWeek` call [`DayOfWeek.of(int dayOfWeek)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#of(int))

Answer (score -1):

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> boolean isEnumContainsInt(Class<T> et,  int v)
{

    if (et == null) {
       return false;
    }
    T[] values = et.getEnumConstants();
    if (values == null) {
        return false;
    }


    for (int i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        T value = values[i];


        if(v== value.ordinal())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why would you do it like this? Surely the element of `values` with ordinal `v` is just `values[v]`. So all you need to test is `v >= 0 && v < values.length`.

Comment: Also, there are at least two redundant conditions here (the second null check of `et`, and the null check on `values` - if it's a non-null subclass of Enum, values won't be null).

Comment: @Andy, what if the enum values are not in sequence?

Comment: they are. That's how ordinal is defined. And even if they're not in sequence, there are as many elements in the values array as there are values.

Comment: @Andy, consider this enum class public enum Foo {
        ONE(1), TWO(2);

        private final int number;

        private Foo(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }
    }

Comment: Consider what about it? The 1 and 2 aren't the ordinal.

Comment: They are, you can check it :)

Comment: no, they're not. The ordinal values are 0 and 1 respectively. https://ideone.com/Nloutk